# In what contexts is "gross" commonly used to mean 144?

Tags: word-usage, descriptive-grammar

Are there specific items that are commonly bought/sold in a gross, or certain industries in which the term is used frequently?

Comment: Could you share the research you have done?

Comment: Why is this question off topic? I just searched for the common usage of this word and this comes up on the first page in G, and most of the other top links don't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Gross is a dozen dozen, so things that normally come in dozens and can be purchased in bulk will likely be sold by the gross. A supermarket, for example, or a character in a [John Waters movie](https://youtu.be/og_85XJTOac) might order a gross of eggs, since eggs usually come by the dozen.

A dozen of something, of course, is twelve of them. The exception is a "baker's dozen", which is thirteen. The term comes from the common practice at neighborhood bakeries, if you order a dozen rolls, for the baker to throw in an extra one as a kind of neighborly "thank you". But you wouldn't ask for a gross baker's buns and expect to get 156 rolls.

Comment: Getting tangential, but [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dozen#Baker.27s_dozen) (and other places appear to confirm) a _baker's dozen_ initially was a way to ensure the correct weight was maintained, and later as the baker's profit (the customer got 12 and the baker kept the last one).

Comment: @TripeHound I've never heard that version before. How would the extra one ensure the correct weight?

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that if you make lots and lots of rolls, the weight of each is going to vary +/- some "ideal" value, so there's no guarantee that a selection of 12 will _always_ weigh 12x that "ideal" value ?(or above). Possibly the 13th was always added "to be safe"; or was only added if they looked (or were) too light.

Comment: @TripeHound I can see that. A sort of cushion. If I were the baker, I'd want it to count as a friendly little extra you won't get at Safeway.